# Method 'ExecuteAsync' does not have an implementation. EF Code First

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

After upgrading our project from 4.0 framework to 4.6 we start receive the error on any migration command running from Visual Studio Package Manager Console.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy' from assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' does not have an implementation.

All EF dll's are for 4.5 framework. I try to reinstal EntityFramewor, delete the references and then choose them again from packages->EntityFramework.6.1.3->lib->net45 folder, but nothing help.

This is is app config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalDB" connectionString="data source=DAEDROTH-LAPTOP\DEV;initial catalog=LocalTest;persist security info=True;user id=Admin;password=1;multipleactiveresultsets=False;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just delete applicationhost.config file from your_project/.vs/config folder.

Comment: Why? What did it contain? This doesn't sound like a solution it sounds like a work around.

Comment: Yep, it's work around :). I haven't time to look at it deeply yet, but it figure out the problem